# Error 429 when requesting data from a site

Tags: java, kotlin, httprequest

In my program, I am sending requests for data (JSON) to the site multiple times. Due to the fact that the requests are asynchronous, I am facing error 429 (Many requests).

An example of my request code:

```
private fun getJsonElementByUrl(
        url: String
    ): JsonElement {
        val `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(URL(url).openStream()))
        var inputLine: String?
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        while (`in`.readLine()
                .also { inputLine = it } != null
        ) {
            sb.append(inputLine)
        }
        `in`.close()
        return JsonParser().parse(sb.toString())
    }
```

Method `getJsonElementByUrl` is executed asynchronously

Is there a mechanism so that I can avoid the 429 error?

Comment: Throttle your requests? Or use bulk-requests if the service supports that. Hard to tell from the question.

Comment: As a side note, there is much simpler to read the stream: `val bodyText = URL(url).openStream().bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }` (it doesn't remove the new line characters, but for JSON parsing this should be fine)